# Creating a SAS Column name with more than 32 Characters to be exported to Excel

Tags: excel, sas, export, rename

I am trying to create a SAS table with a column name that has more than 32 characters. I will then export this SAS table to an Excel file, but I noticed that the maximum character length is 32 characters for a SAS column. Is there a way to create SAS column name with more than 32 characters, so that it can be exported to Excel with the 32+ characters long column name? Thanks for any help.

Comment: SAS datasets have variables but EXCEL does not have variables.  I think you mean you want the column header (values in the first row of the spreadsheet) to be longer than 32 bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SAS cannot support column names over 32 characters, under any circumstances.

You can use *column labels*, though, and ask them to be used as the Excel column names.

```
data class;
  set sashelp.class;
  label name="Very Long Column Name That Is So Very Very Long";
run;

proc export data=class file="h:\temp\test_longnames.xlsx" dbms=xlsx replace label;
run;
```